# Formula To Remove Some, But Not All, Duplicates From A List

Tags: excel, list, duplicates, formula, instances

I have a list containing different words and numbers, a sample of which is as follows:

```
Green
Blue
14
Green
Yellow
11
Yellow
Green
Green
14
```

I would like to create a parallel list that removes every unique word/number as well as every second instance of a word/number - so removes some duplicates but not all. To continue with the above example, the final list would look as follows:

```
Green
14
Yellow
Green
```

As there are 4 'Green' in the original list, there are only two in the final list. There are 2 'Yellow' in the original and so just one in the final, and there are only single instances of Blue and 11, so these are removed from the final list.

Is there a formula or methodology to do so? Unfortunately I haven't been able to think of something clever myself.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
=OR(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2)=1,INT(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2)/2)*2=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2))
```

If it's either an even duplicate or a unique, then it is marked as `TRUE`. Make sure you delete all `TRUE` values at once/disable automatic calculation, otherwise it'll mark the odd duplicates too after deleting prior occurrences.